# Symfony2 accessing mailer service

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with Symfony2 and am trying to access mailer service but constantly get this error message:

{"errors":{"code":500,"message":"Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object"}}

my code:

```
<?php
namespace TestBundle\UserBundle\Utilities;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class EmailServiceClass extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmail($subject, $to, $body)
    {
        $msg = \Swift_Message::newInstance();

        $msg->setSubject($subject);
        $msg->setTo($to);
        $msg->setBody($body);
        $msg->setContentType('text/html');
        $msg->setCharset('utf-8');
        $msg->setFrom('test@gmail.com');

        $this->get('mailer')->send($msg);
    }
}
```

The error comes from this line: `$this->get('mailer')->send($msg);`

From what I understand when I extend Controller calls I should be able to access this service without having to specifically create a service.

Comment: Why do you need to extend the controller class?

Comment: Services shouldn't extend controller class (unless you define controllers as services, but that's a completely different topic). It doesn't work like that. You should pass mailer service as a constructor parameter to your `EmailServiceClass` service.

Comment: could you give me a example of mailer service i can look at. thx

Comment: Here's all you need, including examples: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Answer (score 6):

You should do it another way.

It's the best when your services are POPO (Plain Old PHP Object). Also dependencies should be passed via constructor, so let's refactor your service a little bit:

```
class EmailServiceClass //no need to extend anything
{

    private $mailerService; //dependency as private property

    //we're passing dependencies via constructor
    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailerService) 
    { 
        $this->mailerService = $mailerService;
    }

    public function sendEmail($subject, $to, $body)
    {
        $msg = \Swift_Message::newInstance();

        $msg->setSubject($subject);
        $msg->setTo($to);
        $msg->setBody($body);
        $msg->setContentType('text/html');
        $msg->setCharset('utf-8');
        $msg->setFrom('test@gmail.com');
        //now you can access mailer service like that
        $this->mailerService->send($msg);
    }
}
```

Now of course you need to modify the way you configure this service in Service Container.

You probably have something like this now:

```
services:
    your_mailer:
        class:  TestBundle\UserBundle\Utilities\EmailServiceClass
```

Now you need to add `arguments` line in order to pass dependencies:

```
services:
    your_mailer:
        class:  TestBundle\UserBundle\Utilities\EmailServiceClass
        arguments:    ['@mailer']
```

The last line defines arguments that will be passed to your service's constructor. `mailer` is the name of `Swift_Mailer` service.

More details about how to manage service dependencies can be found in [Symfony's Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Dependency injection is the best practice and the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't extend the Controller class with a service class. You should inject the dependencies that you require using the services.yml. Please implement your service to be something along the lines of:

MyController.php:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function sendEmailAction()
    {
        $subject = //..
        $to = //..
        $body = //..

        $this->get('email_service.class')->sendEmail($subject, $to, $body);

        // Return a template, or redirect here..
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

EmailServiceClass.php

```
class EmailServiceClass
{
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function sendEmail($subject, $to, $body)
    {
        $msg = \Swift_Message::newInstance();

        $msg->setSubject($subject);
        $msg->setTo($to);
        $msg->setBody($body);
        $msg->setContentType('text/html');
        $msg->setCharset('utf-8');
        $msg->setFrom('test@gmail.com');

        $this->mailer->send($msg);
    }
}
```

app/config/services.yml

```
email_service.class:
    class: TestBundle\UserBundle\Utilities\EmailServiceClass
    arguments: ['@mailer']
```

Comment: Don't extend a service from the Controller class. Rather use dependency injection.